# How much RAM do I need per SDE DB

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, performance

Estimating RAM required is never a fixed number. However, there are base figures to follow for example for arcgis server services.

How much RAM do I need to plan per DB?

I'm using SQL Server but expect the number is for all major DBMS.

Comment: There's too little information to answer this question.  The answer is certainly not the same for all RDBMSes, and actually varies by version of database.  A better measure would be, "How much can you afford?"  Also keep in mind that "SDE" no longer exists.

Comment: You say that "there are base figures to follow for example for arcgis server services" but where are these?

Comment: @PloyGeo figures are in the link Marc_B posted, specifically there is a spreadsheet ESRI provide and screenshorts are there. Can this be not closed, I want to offer a bounty

Answer (score 1):

For this type of generic question regarding server "specs" for ESRI solutions, the most authoritative and comprehensive documentation can be found on ESRI's **"System Design Strategies"** Wiki pages:

http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/System_Design_Strategies_Preface